# Size_t variable as loop counter causing segmentation fault. Why does the loop not exit once i = 0?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, size-t

The code causing the problem in question is shown below:

```
for(size_t i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
   cout << i  << ", ";
}
```

this outputs:
4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 18446744073709551615,

and then the program returns a segmentation fault for the obvious reason that it attempts to access my the items at a ridiculous index.

why does the counter not stop at 0?

EDIT: I was using a webcompiler for an assignment. It didn't provide any warnings. Generally I develop locally and then just paste in what I've made because I have had compiler issues before. Good to know I wasn't being completely dumb even though the issue was small. Thanks for all the help! Just figured i'd adda little additional information added after many of the answers were given.

Comment: `size_t` is `unsigned`, think a minute what that means for subtractions with a negative result.

Comment: @cigien I edited the post to remove my specific variable names

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: [Adjust your compiler's warning options.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h5Wzoz)

Comment: The big tell here is 18446744073709551615 -> 2 to the power of 64 -1 Maximum 64 bit unsigned integer. That's a huge hint that you've rolled the integer over.

Comment: A simple switch to `ssize_t` is probably the simplest fix. Or any other signed integer type (-1 through 10 are representable in all of them).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ More directly, think about what `i >= 0` means when `i` is of an unsigned type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned integral. This means that `i` can never be negative. When `i` is equal to `0`, and you subtract `1`, it will become a very large number, not `-1`.

The condition `i >=0` basically says keep running this loop until `i` is less than zero. Because of the type of `i`, this condition is never met.

This is something your compiler could probably point out to you. I'm not sure which compiler you are using. But for example, if you are using gcc, you can add the flag <strike>`-Wsign-compare`</strike>`-Wtype-limits`.

Edit: Changed to proper gcc flag. Credits go to @Deduplicator

Comment: you beat me to it ^^ by 45 seconds

Comment: @Sho `-Wsign-compare` doesn't help that much. What you want is detecting trivially constant comparisons which look dodgy. `-Wtype-limits` gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a for loop to count form zero to nine, you do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Note that the condition of this loop is i < 10. At the end of the ninth iteration, i is incremented (`i++`) then checked (`i < 10`).

In your case, the type of i is `size_t` which is unsigned (aka can't be negative). Because of [**underflow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow), once `i--` is called, i goes from 0 to `size_t`'s maximum value. As this value is positive, the condition returns true and your for loop continues.

### How to fix this?

**Use a `int` instead.** Size_t is generally used to represent the size of a container, no need to have it here :D.

Comment: There might be a legitimate reason to keep with `size_t` in the general case, even though there certainly isn't is this simplified test-case.

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers will warn you if a comparison is always trivially true (or false).
In this case, an unsigned type like `size_t` can never hold a sub-zero value.

Of course, you must profess interest in getting warned, paying heed is optional.

For demonstration purposes, see [the following program compiled on coliru using gcc and clang](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28a66772eb6e3135)

```
int main() {
    for (unsigned i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        /**/;
}
```

If you want to work on that whole range, and stay with the single unsigned loop-variable, rearranging a bit gets it done:

```
for (size_t i = 11; i-->0; )
    /**/;
```

Of course, `i-->0` can be simplified to `i--`, but then I couldn't link "*[What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)*".

Comment: ahah nice reference

Answer (score 0):

In this case size_t is unsigned and obviously it goes to maximum value after being decreased by 1 when being 0. And possibly you use this counter `i` some where in your code to access an array element and then it gets out of boundary, so the segmentation fault!

One simple solution looks like:

```
for(size_t i = 10; i--;){
   std::cout << i  << ", ";
}
```

In this way the loop will defiantly stop at zero!